# {Check Theme Plugin} text domain does not match the theme's slug

Tags: slug

I have these two issues:

> ## 1: WARNING: Your theme appears to be in the wrong directory for the theme name. The directory name must match the slug of the theme.
>
> ## 2: REQUIRED: The

```
<title>
```

> ## tags can only contain a call to wp_title(). Use the wp_title filter to modify the output

**For #1**

Based on what I searched, the text domain is the theme name both of the folder and in style.css. I have checked and they all are the same. Is it because I am using Wamp?

I have also tried inserting this to functions.php and to header.php but that resulted in the same error: *load_theme_textdomain('themename', get_template_directory() . '/languages');*

Wordpress did state this but it is unclear to me that text domain is solely for WordPress.org and not for externally and locally hosted domains or is universal:

> Themes that are hosted on WordPress.org the text domain must match the
>   slug of your theme URL (wordpress.org/themes/). This is needed so that
>   the translations from translate.wordpress.org work correctly.
>
> The text domain name must use dashes and not underscores and be
>   lowercase. For example, if the theme’s name My Theme is defined in the
>   style.css or it is contained in a folder called my-theme the text
>   domain should be my-theme.
>
> The text domain is used in three different places:
>
> In the style.css theme header As an argument in the localization
>   functions As an argument when loading the translations using
>   load_theme_textdomain() or load_child_theme_textdomain() style.css
>   theme header #style.css theme header The text domain is added to the
>   style.css header so that the theme meta-data like the description can
>   be translated even when the theme is not enabled. The text domain
>   should be same as the one used when loading the text domain.
>
> Source:
>   https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/internationalization/#text-domain

**For #2**

I have removed the `<title> and </title>` tags, yet that the error is still shown.

Please help explain, thanks.

Comment: 1. If in your `style.css` file, you've got `Theme Name: My Theme`, then the theme folder should be `my-theme` (i.e. you'd have `wp-content/themes/my-theme`) - and also, the text domain should be `my-theme` as in `Text Domain: my-theme`. Does your theme follow these rules? 2. Is there a `<title>` tag in *any* PHP files in your theme?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Sally CJ. To note, my theme name is a single name. Let's call it abc.||[1. If in your style.css file, you've got Theme Name: My Theme, then the theme folder should be my-theme (i.e. you'd have wp-content/themes/my-theme) - and also, the text domain should be my-theme as in Text Domain: my-theme. Does your theme follow these rules?]// style.css //
Theme Name: abc; Text Domain: abc||// others //wp-content/themes/abc[2. Is there a <title> tag in any PHP files in your theme?]||None at all, I've double, triple, etc. checked.||Could they be false positives?

Comment: Maybe. And if you can share the theme (on GitHub, maybe?), I can help you check it.

Comment: Nice of you, thanks! Sorry for the late response, here you go: https://github.com/Veneripmi/StExchange

Comment: Well, the only issue I see in your theme is that you're using the wrong text domain (`theme-slug`) in [`theme_slug_widgets_init()`](https://github.com/Veneripmi/StExchange/blob/master/ayabil2/functions.php#L14) - and the correct text domain is `ayabil2`..

Answer (score 1):

So that's the cause. Thanks a lot, Saly CJ. The answer is by Sally CJ's

> using the wrong text domain (theme-slug) in theme_slug_widgets_init()
>   - and the correct text domain is ayabil2

(sorry Sally CJ, can't seem to add your reply as answer)